# R mutate - match with wild card

Tags: r, dplyr, match

I'm trying to insert a column in a dataframe `df1` based on a match function pulling across a value from a separate dataframe `df2`.

df1:

```
var_field
abc
def
abc1
2def
```

df2:

```
setting_name setting_type
abc                   xyz
def                   mno
```

The code below manages to do this:

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(match_col = df2[["setting_type"]][match(df1[["var_field"]], df2[["setting_name"]])])
```

I would like to add wildcard functionality to this match, so that it pulls across the `setting_type` from `df2` even if there is not a identical match in `var_field`.

Intended outcome with wildcard:

```
var_field  setting_type
abc                 xyz
def                 mno
abc1                xyz
2def                mno
```

I have tried using the `globrx` function in the code above:

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(match_col = df2[["setting_type"]][match(df1[["var_field"]], df2[[glob2rx(paste("*",setting_name,"*"))]])])
```

but that returns an error:

```
x Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `glob2rx(paste("*", df2$setting_name, "*"))` has size 18 but must be size 1.
```

I have also tried adding in the `glob2rx(paste("*", df2$setting_name, "*"))` as an extra column in `df2` and conducting the match using that instead of `"setting_name"` but that does not work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try the `fuzzyjoin` package. Specifically `fuzzyjoin::stringdist_left_join` and `fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `fuzzyjoin` if you want to join on exact substrings:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- tribble(
  ~var_field,
  "abc",
  "def",
  "abc",
  "2def"
)
df2 <- tribble(
  ~setting_name, ~setting_type,
  "abc", "xyz",
  "def", "mno"
)

df1 %>%
  mutate(setting_name = var_field %>% str_extract(df2$setting_name)) %>%
  left_join(df2) %>%
  select(-setting_name)
#> Joining, by = "setting_name"
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   var_field setting_type
#>   <chr>     <chr>       
#> 1 abc       xyz         
#> 2 def       mno         
#> 3 abc       xyz         
#> 4 2def      mno
```

Comment: I'm getting a `i longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length` warning message after the mutate line in your code above and I think this means it is not working

Comment: It works until its not an error and the result is what you expected